# How to determine file structure of ASP.NET website and roll it into a project/solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

A few months ago I had my first big work related programming project: working on the C# backend of a website (ASP.NET and other technologies). It had some documentation and a `.sln` file, which I simply opened in Visual Studio and got to work on.

This time around, I have a massive amount of C# and VB.NET files with seemingly no project/solution file associated with them. And to add to that, I seem to have no real documentation for the site itself.

I don't really know that much about ASP.NET and web programming at this point, and I'm trying to order some books; but online resources and tips on how to structure this into something I can open in Visual Studio would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's no solution or project file, it may be a web site instead of a web application project. In which case you can open it in Visual Studio with File -> Open -> Web Site.